# IcmpSendEcho returns 183

Tags: c++, windows, winsock, ping, winsock2

I adapted this code example from MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366050(v=vs.85).aspx). It works fine if I build it alone, but if I add it to my application it fails. For convenience I include the exact adaptation of the class I have.

I only want to do a simple ping every second. Raw Sockets don't work without admin rights, and this ICMP.dll approach doesn't work within my application and I don't understand why. Error 183 goes along the lines of "Cannot create a file because it already exists" which makes no sense in this context.

Can anyone spot the problem? Thanks so much for your help.

Ping.h

```
    #pragma once
    #include "Ping.h"
    #include "LogBase.h"
    class WinPing :
        public Ping
    {
    public:
        WinPing(char* address, int period);
        ~WinPing();

        unsigned long           GetRTT();
    private:
        HANDLE                  _hIcmpFile;
        unsigned long           _ipaddr;
        DWORD                   _dwRetVal;
        LPVOID                  _replyBuffer;
        DWORD                   _replySize;

        static HANDLE           _inputTimer;


        int                     _period;
        unsigned long           _lastRTT;



        static DWORD WINAPI     AsyncPingHandler(void* Param);
        void                    DoPing();   

    };
```

WinPing.h

```
    #pragma once
    #include "Ping.h"
    #include "LogBase.h"
    class WinPing :
        public Ping
    {
    public:
        WinPing(char* address, int period);
        ~WinPing();

        unsigned long           GetRTT();
    private:
        HANDLE                  _hIcmpFile;
        unsigned long           _ipaddr;
        DWORD                   _dwRetVal;
        LPVOID                  _replyBuffer;
        DWORD                   _replySize;

        static HANDLE           _inputTimer;


        int                     _period;
        unsigned long           _lastRTT;



        static DWORD WINAPI     AsyncPingHandler(void* Param);
        void                    DoPing();   

    };
```

WinPing.cpp

```
    #include "WinPing.h"
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <iphlpapi.h>
    #include <icmpapi.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "utils.h"

    #pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

    HANDLE WinPing::_inputTimer = NULL;
    char SendData[32] = "Data Buffer";

    unsigned long WinPing::GetRTT()
    {
        return _lastRTT;
    }


    void WinPing::DoPing()
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER t;
        t.HighPart = t.LowPart = 0;
        SetWaitableTimer(_inputTimer, &t, _period, NULL, NULL, TRUE);

        while (true)
        {
            int r = WaitForSingleObject(_inputTimer, _period * 2);
            if (r != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            {
                LogLog("InputHandler: Bad Timer return", LogError);
            }

            _dwRetVal = IcmpSendEcho(_hIcmpFile, _ipaddr, SendData, sizeof(SendData),
                NULL, _replyBuffer, _replySize, 1000);
            if (_dwRetVal != 0) {
                PICMP_ECHO_REPLY pEchoReply = (PICMP_ECHO_REPLY)_replyBuffer;
                struct in_addr ReplyAddr;
                ReplyAddr.S_un.S_addr = pEchoReply->Address;
                LogLog("\tSent icmp message to %s\n", LogDebug, _address);
                if (_dwRetVal > 1) {
                    LogLog("\tReceived %ld icmp message responses\n", LogDebug, _dwRetVal);
                    LogLog("\tInformation from the first response:\n", LogDebug);
                }
                else {
                    LogLog("\tReceived %ld icmp message response\n", LogDebug, _dwRetVal);
                    LogLog("\tInformation from this response:\n", LogDebug);
                }
                LogLog("\t  Received from %s\n", LogDebug, inet_ntoa(ReplyAddr));
                LogLog("\t  Status = %ld\n", LogDebug,
                    pEchoReply->Status);
                LogLog("\t  Roundtrip time = %ld milliseconds\n", LogDebug,
                    pEchoReply->RoundTripTime);

                //needs synchronization here. Probably not very important
                _lastRTT = pEchoReply->RoundTripTime;
                LogLog("\t  Roundtrip time = %ld milliseconds\n", LogDebug, _lastRTT);
                IcmpCloseHandle(_hIcmpFile);
            }
            else {
                LogLog("\tCall to IcmpSendEcho failed.\n", LogError);
                LogLog("\tIcmpSendEcho returned error: %ld\n", LogError, GetLastError());

            }

        }
    }

    DWORD WINAPI WinPing::AsyncPingHandler(void* Param)
    {
        _inputTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, false, NULL);
        if (!_inputTimer)
        {
            LogLog("Unable to create input waitable timer", LogError);
            return 1;
        }

        LogLog("RTT Ping Thread started", LogDebug);
        WinPing* This = (WinPing*)Param;
        This->DoPing();

        return 0;

    }


    WinPing::WinPing(char* address, int period)
        :Ping(address),
        _period(period)
    {
        // Declare and initialize variables
        _ipaddr = INADDR_NONE;
        _dwRetVal = 0;
        _replyBuffer = NULL;
        _replySize = 0;


        _ipaddr = inet_addr(address);
        if (_ipaddr == INADDR_NONE) {
            LogLog("Not an IP Address:%s", LogError, address);
            return;
        }

        _hIcmpFile = IcmpCreateFile();
        if (_hIcmpFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            LogLog("\tUnable to open handle.\n", LogError);
            LogLog("IcmpCreatefile returned error: %ld\n", LogError, GetLastError());
            return;
        }

        _replySize = sizeof(ICMP_ECHO_REPLY) + sizeof(SendData);
        _replyBuffer = (VOID*)malloc(_replySize);
        if (_replyBuffer == NULL) {
            LogLog("\tUnable to allocate memory\n", LogError);
            return;
        }

        //Spawn thread on AsyncPingHandler()
        CreateClassThread(AsyncPingHandler, this);

    }


    WinPing::~WinPing()
    {
    }
```

Comment: Your `while` loop in `DoPing()` is useless, since all code paths lead to `return` so `IcmpSendEcho()` is only called once.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I forgot to remove them in the copy I pasted here, but those are not the problem. I updated the code here too.

Comment: Why do you have two .h files defining the same class? I am assuming that `Ping.h` actually defines the `Ping` class, but you have shown it defining the `WinPing` class instead, which is also defined in `WinPing.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that a much easier, much more stable way of doing ping is using GetRTTandHopCount. Here is an example.

```
UINT ip = inet_addr(serverAddress);
ULONG hopCount = 0;
ULONG RTT = 0;

if (GetRTTAndHopCount(ip, &hopCount, 30, &RTT) == TRUE) {
    printf("Hops: %ld\n", hopCount);
    printf("RTT: %ld\n", RTT);
}
else {
    printf("Error: %ld\n", GetLastError());
}

return RTT;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling `GetLastError()` **immediately** after `IcmpSendEcho()` fails (same when calling `IcmpCreateFile()`).  You are calling `LogLog()` first, which is likely altering the error code that `GetLastError()` returns, for instance if it is logging to a file that cannot be found.  **ALWAYS** call `GetLastError()` before doing anything that may call a system function.

```
else {
    DWORD dwErrCode = GetLastError(); // <-- call GetLastError() first
    LogLog("\tCall to IcmpSendEcho failed.\n", LogError);
    LogLog("\tIcmpSendEcho returned error: %u\n", LogError, dwErrCode); // <-- then use the value when needed
    return;
}
```

Comment: That is a very good point. So the error may not be 183 but something else. ICMP is failing because the return value is 0, but the error code may be something different. Worth checking. Thanks